# I try to dual boot Windows 10 and Ubuntu but after the boot operation doesn't show hard disk to select partition

Tags: boot, 18.04, grub2, system-installation, windows-10

I have a Asus x510uf laptop with genuine windows 10. I try to dual boot Windows 10  and Ubuntu but after the boot operation doesn't show hard disk to select partition. I tried Ubuntu and Zorin. help me solve the problem please !

Answer (score 0):

1. After boot on which OS you are not able to see the hard drive.?
2. if it's on the windows than no need to panic because when we dual boot our machine than you are operating two different operating system on the same machine.
3. In which drive you have installed Ubuntu you will not able to see that partition of the drive
   in your windows.

#### If your issue isn't resolve by above information follow these steps:

1. If you have another issue than restart you machine and try to reinstall ubuntu.
2. If you are reinstalling the ubuntu than grub will give error than go to your BIOS settings and change the boot options set that option to the Windows than you will able to work with your windows.
3. After than just format your partition where you have installed the Ubuntu.
4. And try to reinstall ubuntu you will able to install it properly.
5. Using these steps.